# Unity 2018.2 text color gradient

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I searched for google for several hours, but I couldn't find an answer;

[Gradient UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuwUP.png)
Gradient is unique, because of using four parameters.

[Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiKkG.png)
This is a final text gradient that I want to make.

I tried TextMeshPro and so many things, but I couldn't make that gradient by code. How can I make it using code? Or, how can I show Gradient UI on text color?

Comment: The builtin text objects definitely can't support this. TextMeshPro is...better, but even then I'm not sure I've ever seen a gradiated text effect like this with it. Or with any other text package that I can recall.

Comment: Thanks for help! I will figure out more methods.